# How to Convert the JsonArray string to JsonArray in Angular 4?

Tags: json, angular

```
"[{\"key\":\"432100000000000300BB\",\"payLoad\":{\"payLoad\":{\"firstName\":\"postop\",\"lastName\":\"postop\",\"gender\":\"null\",\"patId\":\"432100000000000300BB\",\"anesthesiologist\":\"[]\",\"bedId\":\"1KY0012\",\"bedName\":\"PACU bed 1-1-1\",\"roomName\":\"Recovery 1\",\"roomId\":\"100000000001U61J3U\",\"key\":\"432100000000000300BZ\"},\"siteId\":2,\"id\":\"432100000000000300BB\"}},{\"key\":\"4321000000000003004J\",\"payLoad\":{\"payLoad\":{\"firstName\":\"pat1b\",\"lastName\":\"pat1b\",\"patId\":\"4321000000000003004J\",\"anesthesiologist\":\"[]\",\"bedId\":\"null\",\"bedName\":\"---\",\"roomName\":\"---\",\"roomId\":\"null\",\"key\":\"43210000000000030057\"},\"siteId\":2,\"id\":\"4321000000000003004J\"}},{\"key\":\"4321000000000003000J\",\"payLoad\":{\"payLoad\":{\"firstName\":\"pat1b\",\"lastName\":\"pat1b\",\"patId\":\"4321000000000003000J\",\"anesthesiologist\":\"[]\",\"bedId\":\"null\",\"bedName\":\"---\",\"roomName\":\"---\",\"roomId\":\"null\",\"key\":\"4321000000000003001C\"},\"siteId\":2,\"id\":\"4321000000000003000J\"}}]"
```

The above JsonArray String has to convert to below JsonArray.

```
[{"payLoad":{"firstName":"postop","lastName":"postop","gender":"null","patId":"432100000000000300BB","anesthesiologist":"[]","bedId":"1KY0012","bedName":"PACU bed 1-1-1","roomName":"Recovery 1","roomId":"100000000001U61J3U","key":"432100000000000300BZ"},"siteId":2,"id":"432100000000000300BB"},{"payLoad":{"firstName":"pat1b","lastName":"pat1b","patId":"4321000000000003004J","anesthesiologist":"[]","bedId":"null","bedName":"---","roomName":"---","roomId":"null","key":"43210000000000030057"},"siteId":2,"id":"4321000000000003004J"},{"payLoad":{"firstName":"pat1b","lastName":"pat1b","patId":"4321000000000003000J","anesthesiologist":"[]","bedId":"null","bedName":"---","roomName":"---","roomId":"null","key":"4321000000000003001C"},"siteId":2,"id":"4321000000000003000J"}]
```

I have tried the below code and was not able to convert it.

```
console.log("my data "+JSON.parse(this.getResult));

this.obj = JSON.stringify(this.getResult);

console.log("Object "+this.obj);
```

Comment: You can convert it using JSON.parse("json string") method regardless or AnguarJS or jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution

```
result = "[{\"key\":\"432100000000000300BB\",\"payLoad\":{\"payLoad\":{\"firstName\":\"postop\",\"lastName\":\"postop\",\"gender\":\"null\",\"patId\":\"432100000000000300BB\",\"anesthesiologist\":\"[]\",\"bedId\":\"1KY0012\",\"bedName\":\"PACU bed 1-1-1\",\"roomName\":\"Recovery 1\",\"roomId\":\"100000000001U61J3U\",\"key\":\"432100000000000300BZ\"},\"siteId\":2,\"id\":\"432100000000000300BB\"}},{\"key\":\"4321000000000003004J\",\"payLoad\":{\"payLoad\":{\"firstName\":\"pat1b\",\"lastName\":\"pat1b\",\"patId\":\"4321000000000003004J\",\"anesthesiologist\":\"[]\",\"bedId\":\"null\",\"bedName\":\"---\",\"roomName\":\"---\",\"roomId\":\"null\",\"key\":\"43210000000000030057\"},\"siteId\":2,\"id\":\"4321000000000003004J\"}},{\"key\":\"4321000000000003000J\",\"payLoad\":{\"payLoad\":{\"firstName\":\"pat1b\",\"lastName\":\"pat1b\",\"patId\":\"4321000000000003000J\",\"anesthesiologist\":\"[]\",\"bedId\":\"null\",\"bedName\":\"---\",\"roomName\":\"---\",\"roomId\":\"null\",\"key\":\"4321000000000003001C\"},\"siteId\":2,\"id\":\"4321000000000003000J\"}}]"
console.log("my data "+JSON.stringify(result));
$scope.stringfu = JSON.stringify(result);
$scope.main = JSON.parse($scope.stringfu);
console.log($scope.main);
```

you need to stringify first and then parse. for my explanation, i have use angularjs you can similarly use this code in typescript.

Comment: I hope this worked please accept this as an answer so that other people can find this helpful @kiran